# Running single task in ECS without Blue/Green Deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-ecs

Is it possible to have exactly one task running in AWS ECS at all time? I don't want to have Blue/Green kind of deployment.

**My Requirement:**

Min/Desired/Max task = 1;

When I redeploy ECS service, then it should first stop old task and then spin new task. Currently it does opposite.

Any reference would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

You can create an ECS Service with `Number of Tasks` as 1 that will set the desired count to 1.

Since you want only 1 task and that should stop and then a new one should come, you can modify the **[Deployment Configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_DeploymentConfiguration.html)** with below values:

> Minimum Healthy Percent - 0
>
> Maximum Percent - 100

With Desired Count as 1, `Minimum Healthy Percent` as `0` and `Maximum Percent` as 100, ECS Service will kill the already running task and then create a new task.

**Note:** Service will de down during this time.

To explain the behavior you noticed, The default values are

> Minimum Healthy Percent - 100
>
> Maximum Percent - 200

and with Desired Count as 1, in this case ECS Service will maintain one running task at all times since `Minimum Healthy Percent` is `100` i.e. `100% of 1 is 1`. However, `Maximum Percent` as `200` allows ECS Service to create another task as `200% of 1 is 2`. So a new task is started first and once this task is stable the old task is stopped.

Comment: I figured this out later. But Thanks for answering.